# Which PEP (design document) decides about using map(function,iterable) instead of implementing list.map()

Tags: python, dictionary, language-design, pep

I was wondering the reason why there is no list.map() in the Python standard library.

There are alternatives, like map(function,iterable), and list comprehensions.

I cannot find the PEP (design document) that explains the *whys* of choosing map instead of implementing list.map()

Suppose we have a list like this:

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I believe this code:

```
foo.map(function)

# or

foo.map(lambda x: x*2)
```

Is more readable than:

```
least_readable = list(map(lambda x: x*2, foo))
```

```
least_readable = list(map(multiply_by_two, foo))
```

This looks readably enough for me

```
it_readable_enough_for_me = [multiply_by_two(x) for x in foo]
```

This *looks more readable to me* but doesn't exist:

```
does_not_exist = foo.map(multiply_by_two)
```

I believe that if that does not exist, there must be a reason for it.

Not just because map(function,iterable) is more general.
I guess there must be an important reason behind that I don't see.

Comment: Generally speaking, `map` takes *any iterable*, including generators and custom objects. That's a much more flexible implementation than a specific `list.map`.

Comment: Interestingly, your expected syntax is actually supported by Pandas. As for the actual PEP, I don't know off the top of my head

Comment: It also doesn't return a `list` so it enables memory efficiency aware coding.

Comment: @roganjosh I wasn't surprised, his expected syntax is common among other languages, but we all know that Python is special (for the good and the bad)

Comment: And among Python, Pandas is kinda special, so I'm not surprised it has its own special `map`… ;)

Comment: I suspect this might come down to Guido's [own opinion](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). I'm not sure that all such decisions are backed by PEPs but, actually, that's something I will now track down :)

Comment: @roganjosh According to that post, `map` was introduced around 1993, which was before version 1.0. The [first PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/) apparently was published in 2000…

Comment: @roganjosh I spent too much time with pandas and I was expecting apply, and map in pandas to be more pythonic.

Comment: Even in pandas, you'd normally be trying to avoid them to get vectorized code :P

Answer (score 3):

None.

[PEP 201](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0201/#lockstep-for-loops), the 2nd ever stable implemented PEP, says:

> This behavior can already be accomplished in Python through the use of the map() built- in function

The `map` function is defined in [`bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/426f2b4f13f392875e7861dbd7f34735731eff17/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1194), added in [commit a6c603](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a6c6037f882573c9965e4fac74765357e42148e4). The previous location is [`itertoolsmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17301e9fab311badbbe26a1efcb2decf637b324a/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L1421), which was originally introduced in [commit 96ef81](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/96ef8115dd6ed006f5fc44fa1b577db23485224c) on 1st Feb 2003. There are no PEPs adding this feature up until that date.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_1):

> Python reached version 1.0 in January 1994. The major new features included in this release were the functional programming tools `lambda`, `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. Van Rossum stated that "Python acquired lambda, reduce(), filter() and map(), courtesy of a Lisp hacker who missed them and submitted working patches".

Comment: Can you clarify what your point is with the first quote? I don't see it. Taken out of context like that, you make it look like "This behavior" is what the OP is asking about (i.e., `list.map`). But it's not.

Comment: @superb rain I mean that the behaviour already existed when the 2nd PEP was written, so it was either added in the first PEP or was not in a PEP at all